# How do I configure windows to start with firefox.exe instead of explorer.exe?

Tags: windows-8, firefox

I am working on web browser only kiosk environment with touchscreen windows 8. I found it better to have only firefox or chrome to run and not explorer.exe because I am unable to disable touchscreen's charms bar. 
I tried to edit `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> Software -> Microsoft -> Windows NT -> CurrentVersion -> Winlogon`   Shell to **firefox.exe** but only black screen shows up.

I tried to edit with notepad.exe and that worked. What do I need to edit shell to have it start firefox but not explorer.exe?

Comment: For some reason, my solution to the question was deleted. All I had to do was write all the directories prior to the firefox.exe. So, C:\Program files(x86) ..../firefox.exe

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps input the path of firefox.exe as I think it searches for the .exe file only in the Windows/System32 folder of your drive. You could also delete explorer.exe and move your firefox installation to the Windows/System32 then input firefox.exe into the Shell input.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox by default does not support kiosk mode, you can however install some add ons to enable that feature - rkiosk seems to be the commonly used one.

See also http://www.brighthub.com/internet/google/articles/107735.aspx for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Use FireFox portable instead of the regular version.  By default, the standard installation may have too many dependencies on Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Kiosk mode?

Charms->Settings->Change PC Settings->Accounts

"Set up an account for assigned access"

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx